# iOS - QLPreviewController - How to stop QuickLook from Rotating?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios4, quicklook

I have QuickLook (QLPreviewController) almost working how I want it, but because of the images characteristics I don't want it to rotate into portrait orientation.I have it configured in the "shouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation" method to only return yes for landscape rotations (see code below for details) but it is still rotating to portrait.

**Note:** The shouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation is a direct copy that is used in all of my view controllers for this project and it is working in the other view controllers.

```
//
//  documentViewer.m
//

#import "DocumentViewer.h"

@implementation DocumentViewer

@synthesize documents;

// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
        return YES;
    else if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
        return YES;
    else 
        return NO;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

}

//-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
//  
//  self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
//}

//Nessary for Enabling User Interaction
- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
    return YES;
}

-(void) createList:(NSString *) document {

    documents =     [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:document, nil] retain];
}

-(NSInteger) numberOfPreviewItemsInPreviewController: (QLPreviewController *) controller {

    return [documents count];
}

- (id <QLPreviewItem>) previewController: (QLPreviewController *) controller previewItemAtIndex: (NSInteger) index {

    return [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[documents objectAtIndex:index] ofType:nil]];
}
@end
```

Comment: Can we see that `shouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation` method?

Comment: I'll do you one better than just that method.

Comment: @Mytheral Can you tell us a bit more how your controller is embedded in your app?

Comment: pretty basic over all nav controller and different view controllers to switch between. I'm using QuickLook to display PDFs, JPGs, and PNGs when users hit a "more detail" button via the class above.

Comment: I've noticed it calls for the DeAllocation of DocumentList.m (above) after it displays the document...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never did find a good answer, so I ended up just using a UIWebView.

But I'm still looking.

Comment: Same here.. I also end up using web view.

Answer (score 5):

In **AppDelegate.m** replace

> return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;

with

> return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;

just like this:

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

Comment: This works as it makes ALL views. Jörn Eyrich's solution above allows you to affect just one class of view. However, two good answers :-)

Answer (score 2):

According to the [ViewController Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/BasicViewControllers/BasicViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH101-SW40), the autorotation is roughly controlled by the ViewController that was most recently made visible.

In your case that's probably the `QLPreviewController` itself, not your `DocumentViewer`. (And you say that the latter's `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` isn't called, which is consistent with this hypothesis).

So the autorotation is controlled by the `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` method of `QLPreviewController`, which in a little experiment of mine seems to allow everything but upside-down orientation.

So what you can do is define a subclass of `QLPreviewController` that only overrides `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` the way you did in `DocumentViewer` and use this subclass instead of the original `QLPreviewController`.

LandscapeOnlyQLPreviewController.h:

```
#import <QuickLook/QuickLook.h>

@interface LandscapeOnlyQLPreviewController : QLPreviewController {
}
@end
```

LandscapeOnlyQLPreviewController.m:

```
#import "LandscapeOnlyQLPreviewController.h"

@implementation LandscapeOnlyQLPreviewController
- (BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation) interfaceOrientation
{
  return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
}
@end
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work... copied what you had verbatim and changed my DocumentList.m to use the new LandscapeOnlyPreviewController.

My guess is that when LandScapeOnlyQLPreviewController calls back to the base class the base class then launches a brand new UIViewController which I have no control over, unless I wish to change apple's code...

Or did I completely miss something from your post?

Comment: I think that's unlikely. Can you put an NSLog() into the `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` of `LandscapeOnlyQLPreviewController` and see if it gets called at all?
Can you post the code of the action method that gets called when the user hits the "more detail" button that you mention above?

Comment: Yup, One of the first things I did... I put a breakpoint in there, then an NSLog and it never even was called... Although DeAlloc is.

Comment: Weird... can you see if the `viewWillAppear:` method etc. are getting called?
Are you pushing the `QLPreviewController` on the NavController's stack? Or are you just getting its view and adding it as a subview somwehere in your hierarchy so that the controller's lifecycle methods are bypassed? I still think posting the action method's source could help.

Comment: If someone is still looking for a solution. I could achieve the desired behavior by implementing  `supportedInterfaceOrientations` returning `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape` instead of the `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation`.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
}
```

Comment: That whole function is never called unfortunately.
But that is a more efficient If statement.

Comment: A bit less verbose: `return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);`